Problemas al implementar una redirección de dominio en Azure
estoy trabajando en la redirección del dominio de una aplicación web desplegada en azure funcionando con una instancia de WordPress, la web cuenta con 2 dominios el predeterminado por azure misite.azurewebsites.net y otro personalizado midomain.net he intentado redirigir el trafico que llega a el dominio predeterminado hacia el dominio personalizado para ello implemente esta regla:
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<configuration>
  <system.webServer>
    <rewrite>
      <rules>
        <rule name="Redirect to new domain" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="(.*)" />
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://midomain.net/{R:1}" redirectType="Permanent" />
        </rule>
      </rules>
    </rewrite>
  </system.webServer>
</configuration>

Esta regla la desplegué en el archivo web.config el cual no existia y cree en la carpeta raiz wwwroot pero, al entrar a el dominio predeterminado no soy redirigido al dominio personalizado, intente crear una regla 301 en el archivo .htaccess pero lei que azure no implementa apache y por ende no funcionaria, también probe con agregar l plugin redirection pero al querer redirigir todo el sitio web arroja error en los navegadores del tipo: midomain.net te redirigido muchas veces
